# C# SQL Server VIEW Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, view

I need to create a VIEW query...

For example:

```
Name                   Count
------------------------------
Kaganoff Benzion       122  
Van Gennep             443  
Michelen Luis          656  
kraig Beno             333  
Mogrobejo Endika       555
```

*all the names in the "Name" column containing two words with a space in between.

Now, I need to order by the FIRST letter of the first word and the FIRST letter of the second word ascending and by Count descending...

The outcome should be:

```
Name                   Count
------------------------------
kraig Beno             333  
Kaganoff Benzion       122  
Mogrobejo Endika       555  
Michelen Luis          656  
Van Gennep             443
```

Lets see if you can :)

Comment: If you're counting the names, each unique name will appear only once in the list and the requirement to sort by count descending after sorting by name becomes moot as it would only be relevant as a tie breaker.

Comment: hi Joe, thanks for the reply. i think that grouping is needed because after sorting the names, one would need to group the names with the same starting letters and sort them descending...

Comment: What does your source table look like? Does that have forenames and surnames split out?

Comment: no. only a space between them...

Comment: First fix your data structure, you may have only two word names now, there is no guarantee that will continue. If you want to sort on separate names, they should be parsed to separate fields on insert. It is a bad choice to do this parsing at the time you run the selct queries.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with HLGEM.  Additionally do I need to count these in my answer?  That's an additional step but not really that bad. If you need to count these, count of what?  Count of first letters that are similar? count of distinct names? etc.  (I just went with your provided count in my answer below)

Comment: i take your remark into consideration...(though i have a guarantee that it will continue) lets say i have two separated columns "Name1" and "Name2", (and "Count" of course) then how would you do it?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this query should work (I've set up my own temp table with your data)

```
create table #Temp (Name varchar(100), [Count] int)
insert into #Temp (Name, [Count]) VALUES ('Kaganoff Benzion', 122)
insert into #Temp (Name, [Count]) VALUES ('Van Gennep', 443)
insert into #Temp (Name, [Count]) VALUES ('Michelen Luis', 656)
insert into #Temp (Name, [Count]) VALUES ('kraig Beno', 333)
insert into #Temp (Name, [Count]) VALUES ('Mogrobejo Endika', 555)

select
SUBSTRING(Name, 1, PATINDEX('% %', Name)) AS FirstName,
SUBSTRING(Name, PATINDEX('% %', Name) + 1, LEN(Name) - PATINDEX('% %', Name)) AS SecondName,
[Count]
from #Temp
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 1), SUBSTRING(Name, PATINDEX('% %', Name) + 1, 1), [Count] DESC

drop table #Temp
```

Comment: Should just state that I am working on the assumption that you have a table with two columns called 'Name' and 'Count' and that 'Count' is not an aggregated value.

Comment: you are right. but this is the result i'm getting...  Kaganoff Benzion 122  
Van Gennep 443  
Michelen Luis 656  
kraig Beno 333  
Mogrobejo Endika 555

Comment: @joy, openshac's query works for me, are you using a case sensitive database or some strange collation that would affect ordering?

Comment: Have you run the actual SQL I posted?  When I run it I get: kraig  Beno 333
Kaganoff  Benzion 122
Mogrobejo  Endika 555
Michelen  Luis 656
Van  Gennep 443

Maybe you having quite copied something correctly?

Comment: thanks man! for your help and everything. my mistake...wonderful! i tried it a lot myself and couldn't... Geniuses are all over here... i bow down :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd go about this with a common table expression.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (Name varchar(50), NameCount int);

INSERT INTO @data (Name, NameCount)
SELECT 'Kaganoff Benzion', 122
UNION SELECT 'Van Gennep', 443
UNION SELECT 'Michelen Luis', 656
UNION SELECT 'kraig Beno', 333
UNION SELECT 'Mogrobejo Endika', 555;

--Now that we have the data setup, use a CTE...

WITH NamesAndLetters AS
(
    SELECT 
          SUBSTRING(UPPER(Name), 1, 1) [FirstNameLetter]
        , SUBSTRING(UPPER(Name), PATINDEX('% %', Name) + 1, 1) [LastNameLetter]
        , Name
        , NameCount
    FROM @data
)
SELECT Name, NameCount
FROM NamesAndLetters 
ORDER BY 
      FirstNameLetter ASC
    , LastNameLetter ASC
    , NameCount DESC
```

Sorry for the first post...I didn't see that Name was one column at first.

Comment: I didn't go this route as the output requested seems to me to be an unchanged Column selection (ie [Name], [Count] in and [Name], [Count] out)  that said if you need to perform a more complicated query a CTE in my opinion is the way to go and this is a good example of a basic one. +1

Answer (score 0):

Unless I just don't understand your question...  It is completely possible to split up a single column in the Order By clause while not effecting the output.

Example:

```
Select [Name], [Count]
from [YourView]
Order By 
    Substring([Name], 1, 1) , 
    SUBSTRING([Name], PATINDEX('% %', [Name]) + 1, PATINDEX('% %', [Name]) + 2), 
    [Count] Desc
```

Maybe I'm just confused though, do you want to derive the count or?  Regardless, output of this exactly matches your requested output.

Comment: You probably want:Order By ... [Count] DESC

Comment: Many thanks, appreciated.  Advice: Heed HLGEMs warning, having a column with two sets of data stored in it is just asking for problems if you ever need to access just one (ie FirstName + LastName = Name).  Now is the time to fix this because it will only get harder to convert later down the road. Additionally your query is easier then too:  Select FirstName, LastName, [Count] from YourTable Order By Substring(FirstName, 1, 1), Substring(LastName, 1, 1), [Count] DESC   (OR nix the substring and just let SQL do it's job ordering First/Last alphabetically)